# Custom properties are not updated for the word via openXML

Tags: c#-3.0, office-interop, openxml-sdk

I am trying to update custom properties of word document thru Open XML programming but it seems the updated properties are not getting saved properly for the word document. So when I opening document after successful execution of the update custom property code, I am getting the message box which is "This document contains field that may refer to other files; Do you want to update the fields in the Document?" If I am pressing 'NO' button then all the update properties would not be saved to the document. If we are going for yes option then it will update properties but I need to save the properties explicitly. Please suggest to save properties to the document without getting confirmation message or corrupting the document. :)

the code snippet is given as below,

```
public void SetCustomValue(
    WordprocessingDocument document, string propname, string aValue)
{
    CustomFilePropertiesPart oDocCustomProps = document.CustomFilePropertiesPart;

    Properties props = oDocCustomProps.Properties;

    if (props != null)
    {
        //logger.Debug("props is not null");
        foreach (var prop in props.Elements<CustomDocumentProperty>())
        {
            if (prop != null && prop.Name == propname)
            {
                //logger.Debug("Setting Property: " + prop.Name + " to value: " + aValue);
                prop.Remove();
                var newProp = new CustomDocumentProperty();
                newProp.FormatId = "{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}";
                newProp.Name = prop.Name;
                VTLPWSTR vTLPWSTR1 = new VTLPWSTR();
                vTLPWSTR1.Text = aValue;
                newProp.Append(vTLPWSTR1);
                props.AppendChild(newProp);
                props.Save();
            }
        }

        int pid = 2;

        foreach (CustomDocumentProperty item in props)
        {                        
            item.PropertyId = pid++;
        }

        props.Save();
    }
}
```

I am using .Net framework 3.5 with Open XML SDK 2.0 and Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
        var CustomeProperties = xmlDOc.CustomFilePropertiesPart.Properties;

        foreach (CustomDocumentProperty customeProperty in CustomeProperties)
        {
            if (customeProperty.Name == "DocumentName")
            {
                customeProperty.VTLPWSTR = new VTLPWSTR("My Custom Name");
            }
            else if (customeProperty.Name == "DocumentID")
            {
                customeProperty.VTLPWSTR = new VTLPWSTR("FNP.SMS.IQC");
            }
            else if (customeProperty.Name == "DocumentLastUpdate")
            {
                customeProperty.VTLPWSTR = new VTLPWSTR(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            }
        }

        //Open Word Setting File
        DocumentSettingsPart settingsPart = xmlDOc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType<DocumentSettingsPart>().First();
        //Update Fields
        UpdateFieldsOnOpen updateFields = new UpdateFieldsOnOpen();
        updateFields.Val = new OnOffValue(true);

        settingsPart.Settings.PrependChild<UpdateFieldsOnOpen>(updateFields);
        settingsPart.Settings.Save();
```

you have to update your document fields on open.

Comment: This seems to result in the document being read-only and asking the user whether to update the fields when they open the document. Which is also what the question was asking about.